# Appropriate way to toggle in Javascript/jQuery without using global variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

Usually when I code a toggle function for example toggling between 2 background colors, I use a global variable as a flag. For example like this -

```js
var flag = true;
function change()
{
  if(flag)
    {
      document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      flag = false;
    }
  else
    {
      document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "red";
      flag = true;
    }
}
```

```css
#box
{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<h3>Click the box to toggle</h1>
<div id="box" onclick="change()"></div>
```

But when I code multiple functions to toggle various properties, the number of global variables increases and as stated by these articles-
[**Article #1**](http://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices#Avoid_globals)
[**Article #2**](http://conceptf1.blogspot.in/2014/02/why-to-avoid-global-variables-and-objects-in-javascript.html)
[**Article #3**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-essentials-of-writing-high-quality-javascript--net-15145)
**Global variables must be avoided**.
So my question is, what is the other way to write a simple function like toggle?

Comment: You should put global variables in a namespace for that project.

So, if you have a lot of variables you're using, instead of:

var x, y, z;

do:

var MyVars = {x:xvar, y:yvar, z:zvar}

that way you can keep global variables but they're organized under a namespace.  And then you access them, MyVar.x, MyVar.y, etc.

Comment: Along with the namespace approach (http://elegantcode.com/2011/01/26/basic-javascript-part-8-namespaces/), you could just simply using a self invoking anonymous function which would encapsulate any variables defined in it to that scope, instead of global. However, there might be a better approach someone could provide, depending on your use case. Have an example of what you mean by "toggle various properties" ?

Comment: Use jQuery.data() - https://api.jquery.com/data/ instead of globals

Comment: @Daved: What I meant by various properties is 1 global variable to toggle font-size property, 2nd global variable to toggle width maybe, etc.

Comment: @NomNom99 When you toggle, for any of them, are the styles set enough that you could leverage a CSS class instead of styles on the element? Since you're using jQuery, you could really simplify things if this is the case.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using addEventListener to bind to the click event in combination with a self-executing anonymous function.

```js
(function(){
   var flag = true;
   document.getElementById('box').addEventListener('click', function() {
       this.style.backgroundColor = flag ? "blue" : "red";
       flag = !flag;

   });
})();
```

```css
#box
{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<h3>Click the box to toggle</h1>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: Since he is using jQuery, I would just leverage the library's .click() handler. Btw, I am basing this comment off the jQuery tag on the OP and not his code sample, which does not show jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) to avoid polluting the global scope with variable names. An example of an anonymous IIFE is as follows:

```
(function(){
var flag = true;
function change()
{
  if(flag)
  {
      document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      flag = false;
  }
  else
    {
      document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "red";
      flag = true;
    }
}

}());
```

by wrapping your code in a function you have created another level of scope and are preserving the global space. [Here](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) is an article on it but you can find lots of articles if you just type in a search engine 'IIFE'

Comment: unfortunately, `change` will not be visible outside the containing function

Comment: True, but if the whole file is wrapped in in an IIFE then you are at least keeping everything out of the global scope.

Comment: @Igor: Well, we wanted to avoid polluting the global scope, didn't we? So we don't make `change` global either. Just do `document.getElementById("box").onclick = change;` inside of that IIFE, instead of using inline event attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the background color property then do the opposite like this:

```
 if(document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor == "red")
 {
      document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
 }
 else
 {
      document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "red";
 }
```

If you have more than 2 options just add elseif statements...

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Module object for the page/site like so:

**HTML**

```
<h3>Click the box to toggle</h3>
<div id="box" onclick="MyModule.change(this)">Change Color</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var MyModule = (function(){
    var boxFlag = true;
    return{
        change: function(ele){
            if(boxFlag){
                 ele.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
            }
            else{
                ele.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            }
            boxFlag = !boxFlag;
        }
    }
})();
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sbznrhgy/1/

Comment: No reason to create an object, you could just return the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [**`toggleClass`**](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method exists for precisely this purpose:

```js
$('.box').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('blue');
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.box.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Click the box to toggle</h3>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

---

If you need to toggle between more than two classes, you can check **[`hasClass`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)**, then use **[`addClass`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)** and **[`removeClass`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)**:

```js
$('.box').click(function() {
  if($(this).hasClass('blue')) {
    $(this).removeClass('blue');
    $(this).addClass('green');
  }
  else if($(this).hasClass('green')) {
    $(this).removeClass('green');
  }
  else {
    $(this).addClass('blue');
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.box.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.box.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Click the box</h3>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

---

If you want to attach a non-CSS property to an element, use [**`data`**](https://api.jquery.com/data/):

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var clicks= $(this).data('clicks') || 1;
  if(clicks>=3) {
    $(this).html('You clicked me thrice!');
  }
  else {
    $(this).data('clicks', clicks+1);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me three times</button>
```

Comment: This would work for toggling 2 states, but what about states more than 2?